# python - generate a unique integer even if multiple scripts are running simultaneously?

Tags: python

I have a function that rapidly inserts data into a database and I need to also store a unique integer for each function.

I was considering using rounded microtime however since there are multiple scripts running at the same time I'm worried about running into conflicts.

Can someone recommend a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should indeed prefer a mechanism to generate the ID by the database incrementingly.

You could have a look at the [uuid module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html) to generate random IDs on the Python side:

> This module provides immutable UUID objects (the UUID class) and the functions uuid1(), uuid3(), uuid4(), uuid5() for generating version 1, 3, 4, and 5 UUIDs as specified in RFC 4122.

As per [RFC 4122](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt) [emphasis mine]:

> This specification defines a Uniform Resource Name namespace for
>      UUIDs (Universally Unique IDentifier), also known as GUIDs (Globally
>      Unique IDentifier).  **A UUID is 128 bits long, and can guarantee
>      uniqueness across space and time.**  UUIDs were originally used in the
>      Apollo Network Computing System and later in the Open Software
>      Foundation's (OSF) Distributed Computing Environment (DCE), and then
>      in Microsoft Windows platforms.
>
> This specification is derived from the DCE specification with the
>      kind permission of the OSF (now known as The Open Group).
>      Information from earlier versions of the DCE specification have been
>      incorporated into this document.

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible approaches:

1. Delegate the generation of unique ids to the database engine. Many engines provide such a facility.
2. Have a centralized service of your own that would generate the ids, and have your scripts talk to that service.
3. Have each script generate its own ids; to ensure uniqueness, incorporate into the id a token that's unique to the script (e.g. process id and/or IP or MAC address).

Comment: I originally used mongodb what made use a class called MongoID which generated a unique hash prior to inserting into the database. Mysql of course has auto_increment, however I'm using DynamoDB and it offers nothing similar. The odds of actually running into a conflict if I use microtime with a randomly generated integer by range is extremely low, but I was hoping for some python function or module that existed.